# Access IIS website from network computer

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have setup a website in my local pc (IIS). I can access the site with my computer using 
"http://localhost:8088" and "http://myip:8088" but I can not access the site from another pc in network.
Anyone can tell me how can i do it??

Comment: via `http://ip_of_remote_machine:8088/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184013/viewing-my-iis-hosted-site-on-other-machines-on-my-network)

Answer (score 1):

If you PC is on a domain the you need to add your PC's name/network name and IP in the **hosts** file located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` of the other PC. Also ensure that port **8080** is available on open on the remote PC. Ensure that the other PC can ping your PC or at least connect to it if ICMP packets are switch off. For multiple PC on the domain I suggest setup DNS and your IIS settings properly to expose your PC to everyone.