# Hosting Multiple Sites through LAN in ASP.NET IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, networking, iis-7, localhost

We have a few services running on our internal server, named `cpweb2`.

[image: CPWEB2 IIS Manager]

The **Default Web Site** is accessed locally by browsing to `http://cpweb2/`.

To enable browsing to other applications, the other sites are assigned a different port number.

For example:

- **CapacityTracker** is configured to use port 8081: `http://cpweb2:8081/`
- **AcpWcfTool** is configured to use port 8093: `http://cpweb2:8093/`
- **ProductionScoreboard** is configured to use port 8082: `http://cpweb2:8082/`
- **ShopServices** is configured to use port 8095: `http://cpweb2:8095/`

As you can imagine, not many people simply remember the web address for these sites.

I am currently creating a new service called **AcpMainframe**. I would like to give it a more user friendly URL like `http://cpweb2/mainframe` or `http://mainframe.cpweb2/`, but I don't know how exactly to do that if **Default Web Site** is not one of my projects.

I guess this question is two parts.

1. Can I get my new **AcpMainframe** service added to the root level **Default Web Site** if I do not have the code for that root level website?
2. If so, how do I go about that?

Comment: Been on here 41 seconds and someone downvotes it with no reasons why. Got to love people.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this question is off-topic; it would probably be better on Server Fault.

Comment: I down-voted the question as it is off-topic. It's a good question, but it isn't directly coding related. You are probably better of asking at a site like http://serverfault.com/ Also, it was in no way intended to offend you.

Comment: I saw similar threads http://stackoverflow.com/q/2184013/153923 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/646370/153923. Both were similar and got several answers, but neither addressed my particular problem.

Comment: Also, those questions are three and four years old; Stack Overflow wasn't as clearly defined with what was on-topic or off-topic back then.

Comment: One of the big drawbacks I see to serverfault.com is everyone there talks like a network administrator. I'm a software developer, so I don't know what they are saying. I start asking what they are talking about, and the next thing you know they think I'm stupid and refuse to give anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use other hostnames in addition to the one you have, you can set bindings in IIS that will allow multiple sites to run on port 80.  Examples can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks David. Looking into that now.

Comment: Cool. I added my new app as a virtual directory after setting the path, then had to go in and set the application pool to enable 32-bit. It is working, now. Thank You!