# Host a wcf service on port 80

Tags: wcf

I want to host a service on a computer where it is connected to the internet but I cannot reach it from my client. It must be a firewall/port forwarding issue which I can't set. I can't ping it but I can connect through teamviewer and browse the internet. Can I tackle this issue with port 80?

Comment: Of course, the service port depends on IIS configuration or on your self-host configuration.

Comment: Thant's great! I will host it on IIS. Care to share a guide/tutorial? There are far too many options on IIS.

Comment: Which version of your windows/IIS are you going to use?

Comment: It's windows 7 and using localhost on a browser it says IIS7

Comment: @George checkout this guide here http://www.cshandler.com/2015/10/hosting-wcf-rest-service-in-iis.html

Comment: @vendettamit I know how to host it the problem is that if i use `localhost/myservice` locally is works, if i use `mypublicip/myservice` it doesn't. There should a portfowarding for this to work.

Comment: hmm.. Then it looks like firewall issue. Try adding a new inbound rule for port 80 with http protocol. see instruction as shown in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4597781/881798).

Comment: There rule was already there. Still nothing. There is no endpoint listening.

Comment: Try to set a dns for your application on IIS using port 80. If you cannot get a valid dns from your intra team, create one, like "company.service.com" and set this dns on IIS. Then, add a entry to your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc) pointing this dns to your server ip and try to access using the dns. If work great, your service will be fine with port 80, you will just need a valid dns.