# How do I view my site on multiple screen sizes?

Tags: mobile, size, device-emulation

Ok, so I know how to write code for multiple screen sizes. But, I have no idea how to view my code on a mobile device before making my site go live. Please help!

Comment: Hey @KeeganBrown, if an answer helped solve your specific problem, I would mark it as accepted.  Otherwise, if it was still helpful, I would give it an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with emulators which can simulate a variety of cellular devices. These can be downloaded using a program called Bluestacks for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Google Chrome you can open a website and press F12 (on windows) to enter Developer Mode.

On the top left you can see a little smartphone icon. [image]

Click it and choose a device. Then refresh the page.

Chrome will emulate the experience of a smartphone user straight from your computer, sou you can test it from there.

This is a view of this question on the emulator:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you are using safari.

1. Enable the "develop" menu bar using Safari > Preferences > Advanced.  Your menu bar should look like this:[image]
2. Go to your website
3. Go to Develop > User Agent and choose the device/browser you wish to emulate.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Use of Emulators.

What you need - is any modern browser. Nearly every modern browser will offer you roughly similar emulator capabilities where you can select a target device/resolution. @intboolstring & @Pither has already mentioned safari & chrome options for you. IE & Edge have similar features (which you can probably explore yourself or see this link [IE Emulator feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx)).

2. Using actual devices.

What you need - 1) wireless router 2) your dev machine/laptop which has a web server (like IIS on windows) & 3) some mobile devices (I would assume you would have atleast one smartphone which has a mobile browser on it).

You will need to connect your dev machine/laotop & your device(s) to the wireless and setup firewall on your dev machine to allow access to your website on your local wireless network. [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32056354/1310498).

Once this is done, you should be able to load your site on any device connected on your wireless by tying http://your.dev.machine.ipv4:port-if-applicable/landingpage.html in the mobile browser.

(to find your machine's ipv4 address, goto command prompt and type ipconfig and press enter - I am assuming you are using windows)

You may be limiting your testing to a much smaller set of devices (ones you have access to). But this will give you a real-world idea (if not a much better one) of how you site renders & behaves on devices.