# Making websites hosted in localhost "port" available to all on network

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-hosting, firewall, lan

I have a website hosted in IIS in my local PC.

I can access to my IIS from other computers in the network by typing in http://my_lan_IP. However, when I try to get access to a specific port (http://my_lan_IP:**8888**) in my local PC, it says the "The site can't be reached."

I disabled all my firewalls and even tried allowing the specific port through Windows Firewall, but it didn't work. [Viewing my IIS hosted site on other machines on my network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184013/viewing-my-iis-hosted-site-on-other-machines-on-my-network/4597781#4597781)

Thanks so much for your help :)

FYI: I am using Windows 10. My goal is to connect to the locally hosted ASP.NET website from other machines on the network.

Comment: Yes, I meant ISS. I revised it. Thanks!

Comment: Your website (server) needs to be configured to serve HTTP on port 8888 in order for a client to connect to that port. By default, your website is served on port 80. Which is omitted from addresses. All web addresses, if not specifying a port, is actually running on port 80, or 8080.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder Your last sentence is somewhat misleading. If the protocol is HTTPS then it will by default be port 443.

Comment: @mason. Agreed. I was trying to provide general guidance. My comment should have read: "All http web addresses". Thanks.

Comment: Probably other machines have also block the 8888 by firewall rules

Answer (score 1):

Your web server needs to be configured to serve HTTP on port 8888 "for that particular website", in order for a client to connect to that port.

By default, your website is served on port 80, which is omitted from normal addresses. All http web addresses, if not specifying a port, is actually running on port 80, or 8080.

Your windows firewall will not effect local connections you make to your own pc. Get it working on your own machine, and then worry about firewalls that block connections from other machines on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by configuring a host header for a website. Thank you all for your help :)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx